# Updating MongoDB Document Not Working

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm simply trying to update a specific field in a document I have for a MongoDB database.

I have the below code:

```
    $connection = new MongoClient("private"); 
    $collection = $connection->testdb->deliveries;

   // Use the ID to generate the actual MongoID
   $realmongoid = new MongoId($id);
   $cursor = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => $realmongoid));
```

So all that works perfectly fine, but when I try to update a specific field in my document with this code:

```
    $arrayWithDriverInfo = array("filledBy" => $_SESSION['username']);
    $cursor->update($arrayWithDriverInfo);
```

It doesn't work. I get this message: Fatal error: `Call to a member function update() on array in...`

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the **[`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** operator in your **[update](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php)** as follows

```
<?php

$connection = new MongoClient("private"); 
$collection = $connection->testdb->deliveries;

$obj = $collection->findOne();
$id = "55711efed0103b1598140076";

$realmongoid = new MongoId($id);
$arrayWithDriverInfo = array("filledBy" => $_SESSION['username']);

$collection->update(
    array( '_id' => $realmongoid ),
    array( '$set' => $arrayWithDriverInfo )
);

$obj = $collection->findOne();
var_dump($obj);

?>
```